# All URLs changed path after upgrading to 3.6?

Tags: url, error

I'm not sure exactly what has changed here. All links are directing to "site.test/admin/site.test/blog/{slug}", when clicking on the link from the entry page. Before they would be "site.test/blog/{slug}". All links across the entire site are doing this. Is there a new variable or setting I need to change?

I have the sites 'Base URL' set to an .env variable, $PRIMARY_SITE_URL which I then have set as 'site.test'

Comment: Do you have `http://` or `https://` in front of the URL in your `.env`?

Comment: No. I unticked 'this site has a base url' and everything went back to working as expected. I also saw somewhere that craft now expects a 'DEFAULT_SITE_URL' in your .env file, so have added that variable into my file now as http://site.test and everything seems to be fine. Thank you for helping debug

Comment: @Thurc1996 Can you add what worked for you as an official solution in case it can help someone in the future?